# Property 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp' but required in type 'App'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I seem to be getting this error when I try to run a fresh install of Angular 7.2 and Firebase:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(17,22): error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'.
  Property 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp' but required in type 'App'.
```

Tried switching between different versions of @angular/fire and firebase, but didn't manage to find a working combination.

Current package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run supynes-full:server:production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "dynamic-import-ponyfill": "^0.1.0",
    "firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "flamelink": "^0.19.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this error? Google doesn't seem to find anything related to the performance property, there are only similar errors, but not the same ones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I'm also getting this error.
Seems latest ver. of `firebase` which is `5.11.0` is broken.

Changing my dependencies to **`5.10.0`** solved this issue.

Important: do **NOT** use any `~` or `^` ver. prefix

Comment: I had the same problem on an Ionic 4 app with
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.3"   AND   "firebase": "5.11.0"

Solved the problem with the above solution. Changed firebase declaration in package.json to:
"firebase": "5.11.0"
Then execute: Delete node_modules, npm cache verify, npm install.

Everything is compiling correctly now.

Comment: @gkoromia the firebase team fixed bug in v`5.11.1`. just tried

Answer (score 2):

Managed to resolve the issue by specifying firebase's version to be "5.0.4", not "^5.0.4".

Answer (score 1):

change version of firebase to the 5.10.1 by the command

**npm install --save firebase@5.10.1**

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

> ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:17:22 - error
>   TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'.
>   **Property 'performance' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp' but required in type 'App'.**
>
> 17 export declare class FirebaseApp implements app.App {
>
> node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts:1217:5
>       1217     performance(): firebase.performance.Performance;
>               'performance' is declared here.

[image]

**Solution:**

Change version of firebase to the 5.10.1 by the command:

```
npm install --save firebase@5.10.1
```

It works definitely.